# Nested Serializer in DRF is not showing field names

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have 2 serializers, Serializer1 is nested in Serializer2

```
class Serializer1(serializers.Serializer):
  field1 = serializers.CharField()
  field2 = serializers.CharField()

class Serializer2(serializers.Serializer):
  field3 = Serializer1()
```

When I am sending a response using Serializer2, the response is coming fine, but I don't know why the field name for Serializer1 is not coming, and brackets for field 3 is coming like a list rather than a dictionary

expected response

```
{
  field3: {
    field1: 'string1',
    field2: 'string2'
  }
}
```

but actual response is like

```
{
  field3: [
    'string1',
    'string2'
  ]
}
```

I don't know why the actual response field3 has brackets like a list rather than like a dict in expected response. And field name for Serializer 1 is also not coming.

It is working when I do this in my view, now response comes like expected response

```
var2 = Serializer1(var1).data
obj = {
  field3 : var2 
}
serializer = Serializer2(data=obj)
serializer.is_valid()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

but when I do this response is like actual response

```
obj = {
  field3: var1
}
serializer = Serializer2(data=obj)
serializer.is_valid()
return Response(serializer.data)
```

My main doubt is when in nested serializer I have mentioned

```
field3 = Serializer1()
```

then why I have to do this in my view, why can't I directly give var1 to field 3 while making obj1 dictionary

```
var2 = Serializer1(var1).data
obj = {
  field3 : var2 
}
```

Comment: how you are using can you add some more detail

Comment: added more details Tanveer

Comment: i m going to add answer please check it

Answer (score 0):

That shouldn't even work (on browsable API), you are missing `serializers.Serializer`:

```
class Serializer1(serializers.Serializer):
  field1 = serializers.CharField()
  field2 = serializers.CharField()

class Serializer2(serializers.Serializer):
  field3 = Serializer1()
```

views.py

```
class SerializerTestAPIView(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        string_data = { 'field3': {'field1': 'string1', 'field2': 'string2'}}
        serializer = Serializer2(string_data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

sample output

```
{
    "field3": {
        "field1": "string1",
        "field2": "string2"
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, actually I have added serializers. Serializer in my code, I forget to mention while asking the question, then my response is coming like actual response in my question.

Comment: Did you try to reproduce the view in my answer, yields the same result?

Answer (score 0):

Serializer1 represents a single object when you add it as a nested serializer into Serializer2 it's mean there will be multiple(nested) objects into serializer2 and it takes it as a list not a dict by default, if you want to response like this then you have to look into the documentation of https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#dictfield